# мобильная верстка

Tags: html

Имеется верстка, внутри верстки находятся два контейнера.
Один контейнер имеет ширину 1600 и называется `<div id="main"></div>`
и имеется контейнер с шириной 1000 и называется `<div id="mini"></div>`
Как показывать `<div id="main"></div>` на компьютерах, а `<div id="mini"></div>` на мобильных телефонах (Android,Iphone и так далее)?

Comment: Пробовал делать вот так @media screen (max-width: 1000px) { #main {display:none} #mini {display:block;} Почему то все равно показывается main версия

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/sbxb8eb6/

Answer (score 1):

> Пробовал делать вот так
>
> ```
> @media screen (max-width: 1000px) { #main {display:none} #mini {display:block;}
> ```
>
> Почему то все равно показывается main версия

Поменяй местами стили, чтобы код в media-запросы шёл после обычного.

---

А ещё ты `and` пропустил:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  #main { display:none;  }
  #mini { display:block; }
}
```